# He lives as he wants

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

Which is correct?

**He lives as he wants**

**He lives how he wants**

Comment: They both seem fine to me, and have the same meaning, though different grammar of course.  I wouldn't say that either is preferable.

Comment: Doesn't the second one look like "he lives because he wants"?

Comment: No: it means "he lives any way that he wants (to live)"

Comment: But aren't "as" and "because" interchangeable?

I did it as\because I had been going to do it for a long time
She came as\because it was her party
He shall win as\because he's never been losing

Then all these sentences with "as" should be like

I did it how I had been going to do it for a long time
She came how it was her party
He shall win how he's never been losing

Comment: Forget "because" -- it's irrelevant. They both mean he lives in the way he chooses to live in.  Grammatically, "as he wants" is a preposition phrase; "how he wants" is a special kind of relative clause.

Comment: I would only ever say: **He lives how he wants to live**. In normal, everyday conversation. The repetition of the verb or just leaving the to out there  is what makes it sound idiomatic. **He lives how he wants to**.  Your example do not great. Or even: like instead of how.

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatical and they both mean essentially the same thing.

> He lives **as** he wants.
>   He lives **how** he wants.
>
> → He lives (**in the way** / **in the manner**) he wants.

---

In the first sentence, [*as*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as#h2) is used in the following sense:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>    : in the way or manner that
>   // Do *as* I do.

Comment: But if I am asked "Why are you living?" I can't say: "I live as I want"? 
Or it depends on the context: 1) in the way - if I am asked: "What way do you live" - "I live as I want" 2) because - "Why are you living?" - "I live as I want".

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko ***Why*** *are you* ***living*** uses two different words, and it means something else entirely. It's asking *Why are you alive?*

Comment: No, I mean for "Why are you living?" we can use "I am living because I want". It's like "what aim are you living for?". But can't we use "as" instead of "because" in the same sentence? - "I am living as I want?"

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko No, you *can't* normally reply with *I am living because I want*. That would imply that your force of will is enough to keep you alive. In some contexts that actually may make sense—but not in general. People are generally alive because they haven't died yet. The question *Why are you living?* does not mean *'What kind of lifestyle do you have?* And, no. You can't use *as* instead of *because* here. They don't mean the same thing. Although you're talking about something else now, you might be able to use *since* instead of *because*.

Comment: Okay, a different example?
"Why are you playing this game"? - "I am playing because I want". Is it alright?
Then can we change "because" for "as" like "I am playing as I want"?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko Also no. Q: "Why are you playing this game?" A: "I am playing as I want." Response: "I didn't ask you ***how*** you were playing the game, I asked you ***why*** you were playing the game. Please answer my actual question."

Comment: So we can equal **as** to **how** in all cases?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko In *this* case, yes. But [as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as) has ***many*** different meanings. What it means in any given sentence will be determined by context.

Comment: In different words **as** is never like **because**?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko See [sense 7](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as#h2) when used as a conjunction: "for the reason that : BECAUSE, SINCE // stayed home *as* she had no car." For further discussion of this usage, you should ask a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

The statement is fine grammatically. The social or target audience may see it differently. As presented, it's vague.

Comment: I would say either of these statements in response to someone unduly criticizing the man's lifestyle or trying to control or manipulate the man or otherwise infringe upon his free will.